# Okular pdf print preview problem

Tags: printing, kde, okular, cups-lpd, kile

On ubuntu 20.04, I am facing problems with printing from day one.
I don't know where to start from. So I deleted `cups` and just focus on `okular`. However, the print preview is coming out bad and when I save the pdf to a file, the pdf looks bad, not in vector format.

I removed and reinstalled okular multiple times from multiple sources. Don't know what to do now. Is it font issue?

Even save to file on `Chrome` works fine, but it can't print at all, different story with the printing!

EDIT: Take the example of this scientific paper
https://arxiv.org/pdf/2105.01659.pdf

All the pages where there is a figure, say page 5, appear extremely bad on print preview. If I save to file, yes it looks bad there too.

**EDIT2:**
I am so curious to know what is happening. So I explain the situation point-wise, please let me know what to blame according to you.

1. I can see some pdf files fine with `okular` but the print in the print previews `okular` messes up some fonts. What to blame-- `okular` or system fonts or `cups`?
2. `Okular` cannot print on any of the network printers installed. What to blame -- `okular` or `cups`?
3. `Evince` shows the pdf files fine, the print previews are also fine. From evince I can print also, but the print outs have very bad fonts. What to blame -- `Evince` or system fonts or `cups`?

Extra info: All mac computers can print the files perfectly. If I print the files from a usb drive, the printouts are fine. `Google chrome` can show the files fine, the print previews are also fine. But it can't print.

Comment: I almost never get much meaningful help from ask ubuntu forum. What is the alternative?

Comment: You say that you have deleted `cups`, whatever that means. CUPS is the printing system. Delete its packages at your peril. You also do not mention the printer model and how it is connected.

Comment: As of now, please forget about printing. I am more concerned as to why the print previews are bad. One of the printer I am trying is: `Hewlett-Packard HP LaserJet 700 color MFP M775`

Comment: Print preview and Print to file hasn't anything to do with the printing system. You can see this by stopping the cups service. `pdffonts` shows that all fonts (apart from one) are embedded in the PDF. I suppose it could be an issue with the poppler library.

Comment: How to solve then? I found `pdf2ps` shows same problem. However `gs` itself can show it properly! Also, `okular` uses `ghostscript`, so does `cups`. Completely confused! More importantly I checked on 4 different ubuntu 20.04 computers, maintained by different persons, all show same issues! Too much of a coincident.

Comment: My only suggestion is to try on 21.04.

Comment: Impossible. Can't leave LTS. But in 2021 one cannot print properly on a LTS distro!! And no one cares!! I am using ubuntu for more than 12 years, sometimes I wish if this was not a free service.

Comment: Also I suspect that I had similar issues on 18.04, I just blamed the printers for the bad quality.

Comment: "...one cannot print properly...". As I have already remarked - your print preview issue hasn't anything to do with printing. Do you not have a spare partition/hard disk/USB stick to test whether the same thing occurs with 21.04?

Comment: Well I will try on a live usb 21.04 session.